# Making sheet name the same as cell value

Tags: excel, vba, accounting

I am currently working on macro in a workbook with multiple worksheets, that aims to show and hide certain worksheets based on the values in a master worksheet. The worksheet names are also contained in the master worksheet and the main procedure looks at these values when referencing to a worksheet it needs to show or hide. The problem with this method is that, the macro will produce errors if the user changes the worksheet tab names. I was hoping to insert an additional procedure that makes the tab names of each worksheet equal to the values in the respective cell of the master worksheet. I came up with the following:

```
Sub SheetName()
If Not ActiveWorkbook Is ThisWorkbook Then Exit Sub
Dim DataImport As Worksheet
Set DataImport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Import")

DataImport.Range("A13").Value = Sheet1.Name

End Sub
```

This code works fine but there are about 100+ worksheets in this workbook. I was wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this, as opposed to typing the same procedure 100 times. I've tried storing the worksheet code names in an array and looping the same procedure through the array, for example:

```
Sub test()
Dim DataImport As Worksheet
Set DataImport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Import")
Dim index As Long
Dim ws(0 To 2) As Worksheet
Set ws = Array(Sheet1, Sheet2, Sheet3)

For i = 13 To 14
index = i - 13
DataImport.Cells(i, "A").Value = ws(index).Name
Next i

End Sub
```

but the error message "Can't Assign to Array" shows up. Sorry in advance if my code looks garbage, I am still new to VBA and I still have quite a lot to learn.

Answer (score 1):

If you list the sheet *codenames* in ColA of your master sheet, then this code will update columns B and C with the current sheet tab names and indexes respectively:

```
Sub UpdateIndex()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, cn As String, m

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        cn = ws.CodeName
        If cn <> DataImport.CodeName Then
            'look for the codename in the Import sheet
            m = Application.Match(cn, DataImport.Columns(1), 0)
            If Not IsError(m) Then
                'got a match - update this row
                DataImport.Cells(m, "B").Value = ws.Name 'tab name
                DataImport.Cells(m, "C").Value = ws.Index 'sheet index
            End If
        End If
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Assumes you set the code name for your "Data Import" worksheet to `DataImport`.

If your code is driven by the sheet codename, it doesn't matter whether the user renames the tabs or changes the sheet order.

Answer (score 0):

For your second attempt, you can use Excel built-in `Sheets` object and `Workbook.Sheets` collection:

```
Sub test()
Dim DataImport As Worksheet
Set DataImport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data Import")
Dim index As Long
Dim ws As Excel.Sheets
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets

For i = 13 To 14
    index = i - 13
    DataImport.Cells(i, "A").Value = ws(index).Name
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi I have considered using this method but I am unsure as to whether referring to the worksheets by their index number is effective in this scenario. The ordering of the worksheets will often be changed by the users, I was told that this would cause problems if you were referencing the sheets using their index number (correct me if I'm wrong as I'm still new to VBA). If this is the case, is there anyway that I can reference the worksheets using their code names? @Doug Glancy

Comment: is there anyway that I can reference the worksheets using their code names? Yes, but not using a variable. If `Sheet1` has a code name of `sh1` that you set manually, you can just do `sh1.Name` (but see how you cannot make that using a variable?)

Comment: You could always just make a function that scans all the worksheets for a specific name, and then have it return the index, and then use that index in your code...

Comment: I see i see. I'm inclined to try your suggested method but will the function run into error if the user changes the name of the worksheet? @braX

Comment: Something has to be consistent, ideally either the order or the name. Otherwise you would need a function that searches for it using some matching method. It cant just be random. It has to key in on something, maybe like the column headers?

Comment: Tim Williams has answered your code name question below. That's probably your best approach.